# How can i connect codeigniter with Sql Server 2012?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, xampp, php-5.5

I have downloaded the driver, and put it into php/ext folder also and edit php.ini file as well but still the database is not connecting.

Following is my database.php settings i double checked the settings all are correctly entered but still having an error **"Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings."**

Anyone can one help me in this ?

It will be appreciated.

```
$db['default'] = array(
'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
'username' => 'abc',
'password' => 'abc',
'database' => 'abc',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are showing for the SQLSRV driver implies the DLL is never loading.

First, you need to download the driver here:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx
```

Now go to your XAMPP directory installation look for `php.ini` and enable the following:

```
   extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
```

if your webserver and your database server are not on same server with your app, install this:

```
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188400&clcid=0x409
```

Hope this helps!